# Updating /etc/ansible/hosts with ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I want to update just one entry from inventory file `/etc/ansible/hosts` depending on some conditions (e.g. change in network properties). From this snippet of my inventory file, I would like to update the entry under `[south_side_hosts]`. Is there a way, with ansible, to update this file? I could write a python script to parse and update the file but was hoping to find a solution with ansible.

```
[south_side_hosts]
sshost.eng.corp.com

[south_side_ips]
192.168.100.2

[num_hosts]
83
```

Comment: Possibly you could use the [replace](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/replace_module.html) module for this, but honestly it sounds like whatever you're ultimate goal is you're going about it the wrong way.

Comment: This might be overkill since you only need to update one entry, but have you dismissed the standard Ansible ways of [working with dynamic inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html)?

Comment: @larsks Thanks for the tip. I will use the replace module. Michal - I looked at the dynamic inventory briefly but it seems too much work to just updte one entry in the file.

Comment: @larsks Without knowing about the use case, I would reserve that judgment, also because the solution is very simple, and Ansible provides a mechanism to refresh the inventory during play. Going directly to dynamic inventory is pretty big change.

Comment: We are all welcome to our own opinions.  I stand by mine, but I'm glad @linuxfan has found a solution that works for them.

Comment: I like @larsks' solution even though he disapproves!

Answer (score 2):

The format of the inventory file is INI, as stated [in the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#hosts-and-groups).

So the [`ini_file` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ini_file_module.html) can work. Use `allow_no_value: true`, and two tasks to remove the old "option" and add the new one:

```
- name: Remove host from 'south_side_hosts' group
  ini_file:
    path: /etc/ansible/hosts
    section: south_side_hosts
    option: sshost.eng.corp.com
    state: absent

- name: Add host to 'south_side_hosts' group
  ini_file:
    path: /etc/ansible/hosts
    section: south_side_hosts
    option: sshost2.eng.corp.com
    allow_no_value: true
```

You need to refresh the inventory after this, if you want to configure the new host from the same playbook:

```
- name: Refresh the inventory
  meta: refresh_inventory
```

Note that if you intend to do this with random hostnames that you pass on the command line, then a dynamic inventory might indeed be what you are looking for in the long run.

Comment: This solution does not replace the text under `[south_side_hosts]` but adds a new value on the next line as `newhostname` Am I missing something?  From the documentation it seems that I have to delete the section and add it back again with the desired value.